# Paste text to an adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've been given a very large spreadsheet that would be better in a database, so I'm trying to clean up the spreadsheet so I can import it. Throughout the sheet there are cells that have some parts that are formatted with a strike-through (indicating old or changed information). I want to cut all the strike-through out, concatenate it, and paste it into a separate "notes" column.

I have this module ([copied from extendoffice.com website](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4831-excel-remove-delete-strikethrough-text.html)) that will delete the strike-through, but how can I change it to copy the text and paste it into a new field?

```
Sub DelStrikethroughText()
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xStr As String
Dim I As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range：", "KuTools For Excel", Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = Fase
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If IsNumeric(xCell.Value) And xCell.Font.Strikethrough Then
            xCell.Value = ""
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(xCell.Value) Then
            For I = 1 To Len(xCell)
                With xCell.Characters(I, 1)
                    If Not .Font.Strikethrough Then
                        xStr = xStr & .Text
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            xCell.Value = xStr
            xStr = ""
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = Fase` ?

Comment: ... must not be using `Option Explicit` tsk tsk

Comment: @Jeeped  Even though it is a typo; it works.......................try it.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - it works because Option Explicit is not active and a rogue undeclared variable is instantiated on the fly as zero.

Comment: @Jeeped  You are completely correct!

Comment: ... which begs the bigger question; who is willing to rewrite code copied unabashedly and non credited from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4831-excel-remove-delete-strikethrough-text.html) into a question with an inadequate narrative knowing that the OP won't understand the rewrite and likely has no intention of ever understanding it.

Comment: Show us how you tried to change the code, and where you ran into problems.

Comment: @Jeeped, *"KuTools For Excel"* If you understood code you might have recognized that as a credit to the creator... (see what I did there?) Narratives on Stack Overflow, in my experience, distract from the problem as SO supremacists will often focus more on the method and belittle the OP for poor procedure rather than provide an answer, which is what this site is all about: [getting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line `xCell.Value = ""` as this is clearing the cell.

There are a couple of ways to do what you need:

1) you can either stack the values in a string separated with a default special character between each value, then split that string into an array and paste the array into a list;

or the easier but a little slower way is

2) to paste the cell value into a separate sheet straight away, increasing row each time. 
something like this

at top of sub outside of any loops

```
Dim listRow  As Long
listRow = 1
```

then replace `xCell.Value = ""` with

```
Sheets("stack strike through").Cells(listRow , 1) = xCell.Value 'change sheet name, if you want to use a different column instead of A change 1 from the cells(listRow ,1)
listRow  = listRow  + 1
```

remembering to change sheet name

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RemoveNonStrikethroughTextFromSelection()
    Intersect(Selection.Areas(1), ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Select
    Selection.Value(11) = Replace(Replace(Selection.Value(11), "<S>", "["), "</S>", "]")
    Selection.Replace "]*[", "", xlPart
    Selection.Replace "*[", ""
    Selection.Replace "]*", ""
End Sub
```

This version surrounds strike-through text with `[` `]`, and removes the text before `[` and after `]`.

To remove just the strike-through text, replace the 3 `Selection.Replace` lines with:

```
    Selection.Replace "[*]", "", xlPart
```